# Finding the most common strings from arrays of strings

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, csv

How would I loop over a csv that has 1000 arrays of strings and find the 2 most common strings in all of the arrays?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not appropriate to ask us to describe possible ways to do something. Instead, describe what you've tried and why it's not working. Show us a minimal example of your code demonstrating the problem, along with the minimal example of data and required output. As is you're asking for us to guess about your code and we'll write code you have to shoehorn into your code, potentially leading to more problems.

Answer (score -1):

```
def most_common_value(a)
  a.group_by(&:itself).values.max_by(&:size).first(2)
end
```

should work for finding them in each array. The fact that it's multiple arrays coming from a csv file doesn't really matter.

Comment: Without an example of the strings and their sizes and the array available, you're guessing about the OPs requirements. Instead, ask for more clarification before trying to answer.

Comment: Do you believe it is appropriate to offer such an answer, with no explanation, when the OP has a rep of 1?.